# Return generic types from a SQL query method

Tags: java, sql, generics, resultset

I am trying to return generic types from a SQL query method but I am stuck on assigning the value from database to the generic type:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T selectQuery(Connection conn, String sql, T[] parameters) {
        T value = null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            List<T> list = Arrays.asList(parameters);
            for (T param : list) {
                if (param instanceof String) {
                    ps.setString(list.indexOf(param), (String) param);
                } else if (param instanceof Integer) {
                    ps.setInt(list.indexOf(param), (Integer) param);
                } else if (param instanceof Double) {
                    ps.setDouble(list.indexOf(param), (Double) param);
                }
            }
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                 //AM STUCK RIGHT HERE************
            }
            Conn.closeConn(conn);
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        }
        return value;
    }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: The database contains String , integer,double etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i=0;
while (rs.next()) 
{
     int type=rs.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(i);
     if(type ==Types.INTEGER)
       value = (T) rs.getInt();
     else if(type ==Types.DOUBLE)
       value = (T) rs.getDouble();
     else if(type ==Types.FLOAT)
       value = (T) rs.getFloat();
     else if(type ==Types.VARCHAR)
       value = (T) rs.getString();
     else if(type ==Types.LONG)
       value = (T) rs.getLong();
}
```

For further reference on [Types in sql](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html)